# Sending an Email from a Firefox Extension with an Attachment

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, email-attachments

I've been developing a firefox extension, which needs to send an email through the user's email client when a button is pressed.

I've been sending email by simply using a mailto like this:

```
function sendEmail(buttonEvent){    
    gBrowser.addTab("mailto:example@example.com?subject=Hello World");
}
```

But I need to add an attachment to the email that is being sent.

I understand that a mailto link can have an attachment under some versions of Outlook, by using an "?attachment" like this:     `mailto:example@example.com?attachment=""C:\example.txt""`, but I've heard that's not cross platform, has been removed from the newest versions of Outlook, so this isn't a real option.

With that in mind, is there anyway to send an email with an attachment in a Firefox extension, without using server side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that Firefox doesn't have this ability out of the box. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1965786/785541) shows how one would do it in Delphi - apparently, using OLE is required if an attachment needs to be specified. What you *could* do is writing your own DLL that would implement this approach, distribute that DLL with your extension and call it via [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla/js-ctypes).

You won't get a cross-platform solution this way however, you would need to write similar native libraries for Mac OS X and Linux. And then you have the problem that the user's "mail client" doesn't have to be an application, it could be a [web application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Web-based_protocol_handlers) - and then you definitely cannot attach files to a draft message.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer (and for Adblock). It sounds like there isn't a ready way to add attachments; writing native libraries for every platform would be more work than my entire plugin, and this was a non-priority request.