# Delphi: Vcl Styles & Drag-n-Drop

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I'm a Delphi-programmer and I have a question. I create a form with TStyleManager and I use skins on my application. But I want to use Drag-n-Drop files in my app too. How I can realize this? I have tried many methods, but ... I could not get to do it. Hope on your help

Comment: How did you try it? What are the symptoms? Did you set the main form's DockSite property to true? What happens in the OnDockOver and OnDockDrop events?

Comment: For a general drag-n-Drop solution see [Drag/Drop inside an Application AND to another Application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/198488/576719). Please elaborate what your specific problem with styles and drag-n-Drop is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I allow a form to accept file dropping without handling Windows messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354071/how-can-i-allow-a-form-to-accept-file-dropping-without-handling-windows-messages)

Answer (score 5):

When you change the vcl style the handle of the form is recreated, so if you call the  `DragAcceptFiles` function before to set the style the handle used will not be the same when the style is applied. To fix that execute the DragAcceptFiles function in this way.

```
 TStyleManager.SetStyle(StyleName);
 Application.ProcessMessages;//process the message queue;
 DragAcceptFiles( Handle, True );
```

Answer (score 0):

use shellApi unit's method `DragAcceptFiles` to achieve what you need . It needs 2 parameter , first is the handle of the Application and second a boolean to specify whether to switch on - off drag feature . to turn on use something like `DragAcceptFiles(Self.Handle,True);`

To respond to drag and drop of files , use

```
Procedure TForm1.RespondToMessage(var Msg : TMsg;var handled : Boolean) ;
const
   FileIndex : Cardinal = Cardinal(-1);   { return a count of dropped files }
   BuffLen   = 255;
 Var
    FileNum : Word;
   FName : String;
   BuffArr : Array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
 Begin
If Msg.message = WM_DROPFILES Then
 Begin

For FileNum := 0 To DragQueryFile(Msg.wParam,FileIndex,Nil,BuffLen)-1 Do   // first time , FileIndex is 0xFFFFFFFF , so
// the return is the number of files to be dragged
// Here the return in fileIndex is the no of files;
Begin
   DragQueryFile(Msg.wParam, FileNum , BuffArr , BuffLen);
   FName := StrPas(BuffArr);
   //AddButton(FName); -- do whatever operation you want with the fileName
End;
Try
  DragFinish(Msg.wParam);  // Free the memory given to drag operation
Except
End;  
Handled := True;
//AddScrollIfRequired;
End;
End;
```

Now include `Application.OnMessage := RespondToMessage` to trap the drag & drop operations.
Hope that helps

Comment: Oh, I know it and I do this in a similar way but with skins this way doesn't work! This is a my question) How I can use skins & dragndrop together

Comment: @Александр Цыбух : It does actually , which skin are you using anyway ? I tried it using Alpha lite skins , and it works without any hitch. Post a sample of your code to let us know what is wrong.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I used standart skins (My SDK - Delphi XE2; Vlc.Themes - TStyleManger).

Comment: please post a sample of your code , as i cannot see any relation between skins and drag & drop . btw , i tested it on delphi 7

Comment: this is not necessarily, because when I turn off the skins are all working well

Comment: I think the point is that the style manager replaces the form handle to his and when I write DragAcceptFiles(handle,true) I define a form as the message recipient. and when the skins are active, ttstylemanager is the recipient of messages: windows messages come to him rather than the form. I think it's because of this

Comment: that is a valid explanation. try handling the message with SkinManager as the receipient . use SkinManager1.OnMessage := respondToMessage. See if that works.

Comment: the fact that tstylemanager no such properties. it would be so easy ...
I've tried to do things (with the online help), but - to no avail. therefore written here, as there are people who experienced it and can really help, I hope so

Comment: if you really want to use skins, you may use AlphaLite SkinManager perphaps ( i use it) .

Comment: i know it, I use this in another program...it really cool skin copmponents, but I want use only sstandats comps. If I can not find a solution here, have to use standard