# How to detect a drag drop outside your application?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-xe2

I'm trying to emulate the tab dragging functionality of Chrome. I want the user to be able to drag a tab to a new location in the tab strip or drop it outside the application to create a new window. Dragging within the application is easy, but how do I detect when a user drops somewhere not on my app?

In essence I am looking to implement "tear off" tabs.

Comment: Is this link of any help, [Drag/Drop inside an Application AND to another Application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/198488/576719) ?

Comment: @LURD: I thought so too, and almost called it a duplicate, until I re-read the question and saw the "to create a new window". That's not "another application"; it's creating a new window in your own application when something is dropped outside it. I upvoted instead. :-) It seems to be a good question.

Comment: @KenWhite, you are correct. Just tried this feature on Chrome.

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of docking?

Comment: @RobKennedy: Now that you mention it, I'd say... d'oh!

Comment: @Rob: I'd have to say the same thing as Marjan. :-)

Comment: @norgepaul: See the Docking demo that ships with Delphi (by default installed in C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\10.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\Docking (particularly the use of TDockTabSet).

Comment: Norgepaul, I think you asked the wrong question. You've essentially asked how to implement one of the required behaviors of docking. I don't think that's easy to do. However, what I think you *meant* to ask was how to give your program "tear-off" tabs. If that's what you want, then please edit your question to make it clear that you're interested in the end result, not in writing the docking behavior yourself.

Comment: I don't see a problem, `OnEndDrag` will be called even when you drop something outside the application because the mouse is captured during a drag. Just test the 'Target' for nil in the event handler which would mean no one accepted the object.

Comment: How could you distinguish that scenario from a drag over a control which refused?

Comment: @David-How about checking that there is a VCL control under the mouse pointer? Seems to work OK.

Comment: @David - I don't know if your comment is addressed to my comment or the question, but in case of the former, if Target is nil and if you have non zero coordinates in the handler then the drop is outside of any of the application's forms (or.. like norge said). There's only the problem of X, Y being 0, 0 which you have to test for a control if the mouse is really at (0, 0).

Comment: @Sertac Yes it was addressed to your comment. Sorry, forgot the <at>. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the mouse is captured during a drag operation, there's no problem with detecting when a drag operation is finished in an `OnEndDrag` handler, even if it is outside any form of the application. You can tell if the drop is accepted or not by testing the 'target' object and if the drop is not accepted, you can tell if it is outside the application by testing the mouse position.

However there's still a problem with this approach. You can't tell if the drag is cancelled by pressing the 'Esc' key. There's also the problem of not being able to set the drag cursor to 'accepted' outside the form, since no control's `OnDragOver` will be called there.

You can overcome these problem by changing the behavior of the drag operation using a drag object of your creation. Below is one example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet3: TTabSheet;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PageControl1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PageControl1StartDrag(Sender: TObject;
      var DragObject: TDragObject);
    procedure PageControl1EndDrag(Sender, Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure PageControl1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
      State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PageControl1.DragMode := dmManual;
end;


type
  TDragFloatSheet = class(TDragControlObjectEx)
  private
    class var
      FDragSheet: TTabSheet;
      FDragPos: TPoint;
      FCancelled: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); override;
  end;

procedure TDragFloatSheet.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if (Msg.Msg = CN_KEYDOWN) and (Msg.WParam = VK_ESCAPE) then
    FCancelled := True;
  FDragPos := DragPos;
  inherited;
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_MOUSEMOVE) and
      (not Assigned(FindVCLWindow(SmallPointToPoint(TWMMouse(Msg).Pos)))) then
    Winapi.Windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[GetDragCursor(True, 0, 0)]);
end;

//-------------------

procedure TForm1.PageControl1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  TDragFloatSheet.FDragSheet :=
      (Sender as TPageControl).Pages[TPageControl(Sender).IndexOfTabAt(X, Y)];
  PageControl1.BeginDrag(False);
end;

procedure TForm1.PageControl1StartDrag(Sender: TObject;
  var DragObject: TDragObject);
begin
  DragObject := TDragFloatSheet.Create(Sender as TPageControl);
end;

procedure TForm1.PageControl1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  TargetSheet: TTabSheet;
begin
  TargetSheet :=
      (Sender as TPageControl).Pages[TPageControl(Sender).IndexOfTabAt(X, Y)];
  Accept := Assigned(TargetSheet) and (TargetSheet <> TDragFloatSheet.FDragSheet);
end;

procedure TForm1.PageControl1EndDrag(Sender, Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Assigned(Target) then begin

    // normal processing, f.i. find the target tab as in OnDragOver
    // and switch positions with TDragFloatSheet.FDragSheet

  end else begin
    if not TDragFloatSheet.FCancelled then begin
      if not Assigned(FindVCLWindow(TDragFloatSheet.FDragPos)) then begin

        // drop TDragFloatSheet.FDragSheet at TDragFloatSheet.FDragPos

      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```